# Why this Hibernate MySQL Connection is read-only?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring

I have an application using Spring with Hibernate on a MySQL database. For some reason, as of the last few days, anytime I try to persist any objects to my database I am getting the following error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Connection is read-only. Queries leading to data modification are
>   not allowed.***

I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening. My application was working fine a few days ago.

I am configuring a SessionFactory object in my applicationContext.xml file like this:

```
     <bean id="sessionFactory" lass="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
         <property name="configLocation"
 value="classpath:/hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
         <property name="packagesToScan">
             <list>
                 <value>com.domain.domainObjects</value>
             </list>
         </property>
     </bean>
```

my hibernate.cfg.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://{url to db}:3306/{db name}</property>
        <property name="connection.username">{db user}</property>
        <property name="connection.password">{db password}</property>
        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>
        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management >
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property-->
        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I am using a the mysql/j conenction version 5.1, hibernate version 3.2, spring mvc 3.0.5

Comment: The configuration looks good. Please, add also a sample code which is affected by this. Also, it would be nice if you could specify the exact version of the MySQL driver.

Comment: Are you using the Transactional annotation? Is it set to @Transactional(readOnly = true)

Comment: After about 3 hours of horrible debugging I now know what's going on. I have a service-level method that I also have an "around" advice on. The service-level method is annotated with @Transactional(readOnly=true), however, I have another service in my advice that was annotated with @Transactional(readOnly=false). My aspect (or advice) is using the same DAO objects as my normal service-layer, so when I called sessionFactory.getCurrenctSession() it's giving me back the session that was created for my Read-Only Service-level method. Now, I have to re-architect. Thanks for your responses!

Comment: @ElGuapo please close the question.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

After about 3 hours of horrible debugging I now know what's going on. I have a service-level method that I also have an "around" advice on. The service-level method is annotated with `@Transactional(readOnly=true)`, however, I have another service in my advice that was `annotated with @Transactional(readOnly=false)`.

My aspect (or advice) is using the same DAO objects as my normal service-layer, so when I called `sessionFactory.getCurrenctSession()` it's giving me back the session that was created for my Read-Only Service-level method. Now, I have to re-architect.

Comment: We ran into this exact same scenario. We had a readOnly=true method, M1, that wrapped a call to another method M2, that was readOnly=false. Interestingly, we're only seeing this some of the time which I can't quite figure out.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the bug they have in MySQL Connector/J for versions up to 5.1.6:
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=38747

Make sure that version is your case at least 5.1.7

Comment: above answer is an architectural one, this solutions helps me even if my service is having both the type of transactions and no custom advice on them.