# Oauth2 Spring-boot read-only connection error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-oauth2

I am continuously getting below error , I did enable transaction with **@EnableTransactionManagement**, but still somehow transaction is not invoked in **DefaultTokenServices**.

Any help will be much appreciated

**Note:** it was working with spring-boot 1.5 and recently I upgraded to 2.1

```
2020-11-19 18:27:12.385 ERROR 49065 [tomcat-exec-2] - o.s.s.o.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint  : Handling error: TransientDataAccessResourceException, PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [insert into oauth_access_token (token_id, token, authentication_id, user_name, client_id, authentication, refresh_token) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; Connection is read-only. Queries leading to data modification are not allowed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection is read-only. Queries leading to data modification are not allowed

org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [insert into oauth_access_token (token_id, token, authentication_id, user_name, client_id, authentication, refresh_token) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; Connection is read-only. Queries leading to data modification are not allowed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection is read-only. Queries leading to data modification are not allowed
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:110)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
```

Comment: Connection is read-only. Queries leading to data modification are not allowed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection is read-only. Queries leading to data modification are not allowed =======>>> It means you are not able to do queries with modify your db.

You probably have a method or component with @Transactional(readOnly=true)


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648170/why-this-hibernate-mysql-connection-is-read-only

Comment: The Annotation in is @Transaction in DefaultTokenServices.createAccessToken, which is default implementation of oauth

Comment: Could you paste how you are configuring/setting this up.  I am curious to see if you have a method that is calling the authservice, if so your method needs to have @Transactional

Comment: It is the default code of oauth2 in spring boot. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/ef8d78403d551ca9c23c6de4db0aa6aae2e24d79/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/DefaultTokenServices.java#L94

Comment: @SusanMustafa I added solution below which  works but still don't know why transaction is not invoked in  DefaultTokenServices

Answer (score 0):

> 1. solution

I am able to fix with hack by manually attaching transaction to oauth jdbctokenservice.

```
 private static final String AOP_POINTCUT_EXPRESSION = "execution (* org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore.*(..))";

    @Autowired
    public void txAdvice(TransactionInterceptor txAdvice) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        DefaultTransactionAttribute required = new DefaultTransactionAttribute();
        MethodMapTransactionAttributeSource source = new MethodMapTransactionAttributeSource();
        final Method method = JdbcTokenStore.class.getMethod("storeAccessToken", OAuth2AccessToken.class, OAuth2Authentication.class);
        source.addTransactionalMethod(method, required);
        txAdvice.setTransactionAttributeSource(source);
    }

    @Bean
    public Advisor txAdviceAdvisor(TransactionInterceptor txAdvice) {
        AspectJExpressionPointcut pointcut = new AspectJExpressionPointcut();
        pointcut.setExpression(AOP_POINTCUT_EXPRESSION);
        return new DefaultPointcutAdvisor(pointcut, txAdvice);
    }
```

I also created issue with spring-security-oauth but seems it is not supposed to support spring-boot 2.x.

**Any Brilliant mind wanna help on why Transaction was not invoked in DefaultTokenServices.**

> 2. Solution

Create Bean for DefaultTokenServices and pass it to configurer

```
@Autowired
        private DefaultTokenServices tokenServices;

@Bean
        @Primary
        public DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices() {
            DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
            defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
            return defaultTokenServices;
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
                throws Exception {
            endpoints.authorizationCodeServices(authorizationCodeServices())
                    .tokenStore(tokenStore)
                    .authenticationManager(auth)
                    .addInterceptor(handlerInterceptor)
                    .tokenServices(tokenServices)
                    .approvalStoreDisabled();
        }
```

link: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/1900